# firebaseのデータ取得

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

タイトルの通りrealtime databaseの情報取得で困っています。
具体的には、jsonツリーの一番上の階層の情報を取りに行きたいのですが、ランダム関数で作った値をsetValueしているので、値を指定してそのデータを取得することができません。
ちなみにswiftなのですが、何かいい方法があれば教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 1):

`Realtime Database`は、`JSON ツリー`なので一番上の階層にランダム値を指定すると扱いに困ると思います。`Realtime Database`は、Json形式でExportできるので、作成し直した方が早いと思います。

また、`Cloud Firestore`がもう少ししたら正式リリースされます。`Cloud Firestore`の場合は、主キーだけでなくインデックスを使った検索ができるので、`Realtime Database`よりも柔軟な検索が可能です。どういうデータかによるのですが、`Cloud Firestore`に移行することも検討してみてはどうですか。

Comment: ご返事遅れました。
参考にさせていただきます。
ありがとうございました！